# I am using dataTables and need to add arrows to scroll horizontally by column

Tags: css, datatable, datatables

I need to create a table that has the ability to smoothly scroll horizontally, which I am able to easily accomplish with [dataTables](http://datatables.net/), however I also need to be able to scroll the table by column with left and right arrows in the header. Roughly something like this:
[image: arrows]

http://jsfiddle.net/dab927km/2/

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading One</th>
      <th>Heading Two</th>
      <th>Heading Three</th>
      <th>Heading Four</th>
      <th>Heading Five</th>
      <th>Heading Six</th>
      <th>Heading Seven</th>
      <th>Heading Eight</th>
      <th>Heading Nine</th>
      <th>Heading Ten</th>
      <th>Heading Eleven</th>
      <th>Heading Twelve</th>
      <th>Heading Thirteen</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum dolor</td>
      <td>sit amet</td>
      <td>845</td>
      <td>941185</td>
      <td>$20.00</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>laborum quisquam</td>
      <td>libero</td>
      <td>--</td>
      <td>laborum quisquam</td>
      <td>libero</td>
      <td>--</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that your table layout is static, wrapped into a `.wrapper`, you can easily place the arrows with `relative` positioning :

```
.scroll {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-size: bold;  
    color: red;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;    
}
.scroll:hover {
    color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;  
}
.left-scroll { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    left: -20px;
    top: 77px;
}    
.right-scroll { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 550px;
    top: 77px;
}
```

The add the arrows to the `.wrapper` :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="scroll left-scroll"> &#171;</span>
    <span class="scroll right-scroll">&#187;</span>    
    <table class="table">
    ...
```

NB : Dont know what symbols you are using, you may of course use whatever you like, or use some image icons instead. Now simply use [**`scrollLeft`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) on the `.dataTables_scrollBody` element :

```
$(".right-scroll").on('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft += 40;
}) 
$(".left-scroll").on('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft -= 40;
})
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/drrqgnwv/**

[image]

---

**Update** : move by columns, not by a fixed number :

```js
var colIndex = 0, widths = [];
$('.dataTable thead th').each(function() {
    widths.push(parseInt(this.style.width)+16);
})

$(".right-scroll").on('click', function() {
    if (colIndex == widths.length-1) return;
    document.querySelector('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft += widths[colIndex];
    colIndex++;
}) 
$(".left-scroll").on('click', function() {
    if (colIndex == 0) return;
    colIndex--;        
    var scrollLeft = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<colIndex;i++) { scrollLeft+=widths[i] }
    document.querySelector('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/o7zucg4s/**

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I actually want it to scroll by column however. So if you hit the right arrow, I want it to shift the table so that the second column is first, etc. I see that in your example it scrolls 40px but in my case the columns would be different sizes. Is this possible?